# Generating a 2D grid in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Learning haskell and want a function to generate a 2D grid similar to how you might in C:

```
int data[3][3]
```

what's an acceptable and elegant approach? Zip? Foldl?

I could declare one like:

```
x = [[0,0,0],
     [0,0,0],
     [0,0,0]]
```

But I would like a function with x y parameters. Struggling to understand the easiest way without for/while loops :(

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"?

Comment: @Cyclone: What do for/while loops look like in Haskell?

Comment: @Gabe: I'd imagine something like http://www.xoltar.org/old_site/2003//sep/09/haskellLoops.html

Comment: @cyclone Even then, you have the issue of most Haskell data structures, such as Data.Array, being immutable.  This means you can't piece-wise initialize the array.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You seem to be asking "what should I use instead of Arrays in Haskell", right?  You asked about using lists, which certainly aren't arrays and should be avoided for any serious work requiring non-sequential access (for example, lists give O(n) element access instead of O(1)).

The packages you should consider: array (old, standard Haskell arrays), vector (new, uses stream fusion, fast, an API that's actually reasonable, boxed or unboxed, but only one dimension unless you nest them), and repa (only works on newer GHC versions, but allows multi-dimensional arrays and parallel operations even on unboxed representations).

The easiest way to initialize any of these (I assume you mean "initialize" when you say "generate") is their respective "fromList" functions.  For example:

```
import Data.Vector as V
...
    V.fromList $ map V.fromList [[01,02,03],[11,12,13],[22,22,23]]
```

Comment: Fair points, TomMD! I sort of object to the term "serious work" though – performance critical is a better description IMHO.

Comment: vicvicvic: Right, I _just_ edited that part to better call out that I mean performance critical non-sequential access.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a list of lists (`:: [[a]]`), possibly with some new type to ensure that that all lists are of equal length.

To create a list containing `n` values, you can use `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`, so to generate a list of lists, you'd just replicate the list again...

```
grid :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]]
grid x y = replicate y . replicate x
```

Here, the `a` parameter allows you to generate lists with any "zero" value of any type. This can be used like so:

```
> grid 3 3 0
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
> grid 2 3 False
[[False,False],[False,False],[False,False]]
```

EDIT: This coordinate system uses `(y, x)` I realize (I was thinking in `(row, column)`). You can just swap the x and y in `grid` to get the "usual" system.

Comment: Lists are a very poor replacement for arrays.  Unless you're sure you won't have any performance issues, Dominic, I would consider a different data structure with O(1) access.

Comment: Wow that is very elegant. Thank you. Now to understand replicate!

Comment: @TomdMD. Hmm well whilst performance isn't critical, I'd rather not use a naive solution when better ones exist. Will look into Data.Vector

Comment: @Dominic: replicate is actually really simple. You just give it an n and an element and it gives you a list of length n filled with element (e.g., replicate 3 0 = [0,0,0]).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have something not too complicated with fast reads and reasonable fast "updates", you should consider using a `Map` (`import Data.Map`) with `(x,y)` pairs as keys. Add helper functions for range checks and for returning default values for missing entries, and you have a good replacement (as long as the matrix isn't huge)